# bitcoin.conf missing

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf

According to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin , for default bitcoin datadir `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin\`, the typical path to configuration file is `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin\bitcoin.conf`

But bitcoin is filling up my C: drive real quick so i moved the bitcoin datadir to D: drive by creating shortcut with the parameter : `"D:\Bitcoin Core\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe" -datadir="d:\Bitcoin Core\Data"`

But i can't find the bitcoin.conf in the datadir , i even used file explorer search to search in the datadir and in the folder that contains the datadir folder.
[image]

That image is the only result from the search , bitcoin-conf.md is not the bitcoin.conf i am looking for , so it is obvious the bitcoin.conf is not in the datadir.

Where is the bitcoin.conf ?!?!?
I swear there is no Bitcoin folder in %APPDATA%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out that `bitcoin.conf` are not generated just by installing and running bitcoin core.

1. Run bitcoin core and wait until it's fully open.
2. Go to settings > option
3. Click "Open configuration file" , and click "OK", if you haven't installed software that can modify a `.conf` file, the operating system will ask you to choose software to open it. If you're using windows 8, click "More options", and select Notepad.
4. Now the `bitcoin.conf` is opened, save the file and the bitcoin.conf will now appear in the datadir.