# I downloaded blockchain completely, but now trying to open Core, starts download "all" blocks again. Why doesn't it see data file, with block history?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

Windows 10, external 1TB HDD SSD:

- I accidentally clicked "Reset Options" becomes in Core, within the Settings menu.
- In the data file, there are still blocks downloaded from every day of the 2 weeks it took me to sync the blockchain before.
- I still have the blocks in existing data file, from 2009+.

Comment: Hi Felix, if you want to reply, please add a comment to a post. If you have another question, please start a new topic. Our page works a bit differently from a forum. You can find an overview here: [tour].

Comment: Here is some information about how to create a bitcoin.conf on Windows: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/109883/5406, for the question about the interaction with Sparrow and Bitcoin Core, it might be better to start another topic.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have had a custom data directory and "Reset Options" changed it back to the default data directory. You could try to set the custom data directory back to where you know the data to be.